# how to use gprof in Linux?

Tags: linux, gprof

I have a C code in a file `test.c` .I have to profile it using **grof**.I have used the following commands to do so.

`gcc -p -o result test.c

./result

gprof result`

A section of the output looks as follows:

`Flat profile:
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

%   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name`

The problem is no matter what complex or easy program I use **each sample** count doesn't change from 0.01 seconds.Why is that and no time is being accumulated and displayed under the various coloumns.

Comment: Is there some other way I can do it? "have to " means I have to profile it I doesn't neccessarily mean using gprof.

Comment: Well, when I have the objective of locating code to optimize so the app is as fast as possible (as opposed to just measuring how long it takes), [this is how I do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). I've been doing this an awful long time, and I'm still mystified that it's not simply considered obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong command-line option to gcc.  `-p` is for a different, older profiler  - for `gprof`, you need `-pg`.

If you still see no time acculmulated, it just means that your program didn't consume enough CPU time to register - `gprof` uses sample-based profiling, and it didn't run long enough for any samples to be taken.

Comment: Can you recommend another way to profile cpu consuming?