# Why is gccgo slower than gc in that particular case?

Tags: go, gprof

I'm sure everyone knowing `golang` knows that [blog post](http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html) here.

Reading it again, I wondered if using `gccgo` instead of `go build` would increase the speed a bit more. In my typical use case (scientific computations), a `gccgo`-generated binary is always faster than a `go build`-generated one.

So, just grab this file: [havlak6.go](http://code.google.com/p/benchgraffiti/source/browse/havlak/havlak6.go) and compile it:

```
go build havlak6.go -O havlak6_go
gccgo -o havlak6_gccgo -march=native -Ofast havlak6.go
```

Surprise !

```
$/usr/bin/time ./havlak6_go
5.45user 0.06system 0:05.54elapsed 99%CPU

$/usr/bin/time ./havlak6_gccgo
11.38user 0.16system 0:11.74elapsed 98%CPU
```

I'm curious and want to know why an "optimizing" compiler does produce slower code.

I tried to use `gprof` on `gccgo` generated binary:

```
gccgo -pg -march=native -Ofast havlak6.go
./a.out
gprof a.out gmon.out
```

with no luck:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated
```

As you can see the code has not been actually profiled.

Of course, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816274/how-to-use-gprof-in-linux), but as you can see, the program takes 10+ seconds to execute... The number of samples should be > 1000.

I also tried:

```
rm a.out gmon.out
LDFLAGS='-g -pg' gccgo -g -pg -march=native -Ofast havlak6.go
./a.out
gprof
```

No success neither.

Do you know what's wrong? Do you have an idea of why `gccgo`, with all its optimization routines fails to be faster than `gc` in this case?

`go` version: 1.0.2
`gcc` version: 4.7.2

**EDIT:**

Oh, I completely forgot to mention... I obviously tried pprof on the `gccgo`-generated binary... Here is a `top10`:

```
Welcome to pprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(pprof) top10
Total: 1143 samples
    1143 100.0% 100.0%     1143 100.0% 0x00007fbfb04cf1f4
       0   0.0% 100.0%      890  77.9% 0x00007fbfaf81101e
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.3% 0x00007fbfaf8deb64
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.1% 0x00007fbfaf8f2faf
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.3% 0x00007fbfaf8f2fc5
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.1% 0x00007fbfaf8f2fc9
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.1% 0x00007fbfaf8f2fd6
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.1% 0x00007fbfaf8f2fdf
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.2% 0x00007fbfaf8f4a2f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.1% 0x00007fbfaf8f4a33
```

And that's why I'm looking for something else.

**EDIT2:**

Since it seems that someone wants my question to be closed, I did not try to use `gprof` out of the blue: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/1xESoT5Xcd0/bpMvxQeJguMJ

Comment: People still [*believe in gprof as the canonical profiler.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771). Some points: 1) gprof is only useful for CPU-bound programs with shallow call stacks, without recursion, for which it has all symbols. 2) Compiler optimization only makes a difference in tight inner loops or routines called a lot, in your code, that don't themselves call functions (like memory allocation, etc). Compiler optimization doesn't just make everything go faster.

Comment: Yes, I got it for gprof. And I do agree with you about the compiler optimizations. However, I would not expect worse performances either with an optimisation-capable compiler. Performances should be equal or better. If not, there is room for improvement and I'd like to understand why :)

Comment: The only timing I ever do is end-to-end, possibly repeated 10^n times and divided by that, and I don't look for more than 3 digits accuracy. There's noise and I don't care. Then I use random pausing to look for ways to make it faster. Unless it's already been squeezed like a sponge, I will find ways, and then I can do it all over again. When after several cycles I hit diminishing returns, and the pc is most often in my generated instructions, then I turn on the optimizer, which makes it maybe 10% faster. Whoopee.

Answer (score 2):

Running the gccgo-generated binary under Valgrind seems to indicate that `gccgo` has an inefficient memory allocator. This may be one of the reasons why `gccgo` 4.7.2 is slower than `go` 1.0.2. It is impossible to run a binary generated by go 1.0.2 under Valgrind, so it is hard to confirm for a fact whether memory allocation is gccgo's primary performance problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Valgrind`. That's the very first time I dig into profiling and I though gprof was the profiler... I was wrong :) However it seems that `Valgrind` is a C-only profiler/profiling framework. It complains about uninitialised values and does not seem to "get" go at all... Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I used `valgrind --tool=callgrind` and KCacheGrind to examine the behavior of the gccgo-generated code. Valgrind's callgrind is also able to run many non-C codes, but unfortunately it is making assumptions which are violated by go1.0.2-generated binaries. https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=782

Answer (score 0):

Remember `go build` also defaults to static linking so for an apples to apples comparison you should give gccgo the `-static` or `-static-libgo` option.